# Apache Rewrite/Redirect different for TLD vs directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've migrated the content of a site from one domain to another.  I have .htaccess Rewrite set up successfully to redirect any request to the old domain to the same location on the new domain, which is working fine, using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^roundeltable.com
rewriteRule ^(.*) http://wheelspin.tv/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I want to go a little further.  When somebody simply requests the old TLD (http://roundeltable.com/) I want them to be redirected to a specific page within the new domain (http://wheelspin.tv/rt).  If they make a request to any other location from the old domain (for example, http://roundeltable.com/about) I want them to be sent to that exact same place at the new domain (http://wheelspin.tv/about) the way they currently are now.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found the solution to this issue, which ended up being provided by somebody from Media Temple's service department.  Here's the entire code required in the .htaccess file to make this work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://wheelspin.tv/rt/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wheelspin.tv/$1
```

Obviously substitute whatever domain you want to redirect to in place of mine, but that's the solution for my example.  Thanks for the help!

If you want to see all the details on my solution, I have it here: [christiaanconover.com/media-temple-service-rocks/](http://christiaanconover.com/media-temple-service-rocks/)